# Socket.io Engine.io problems "?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OUAHy-a 404"

Tags: javascript, server, socket.io, cors, engine.io

When I try to connect the client to my website with socket.io, it just spams
`https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OUAHy-a 404` (At other times the request has just timed out instead of 404) repeatedly in the client console.
Here is the client html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Zesty testy</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="./client.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the client js:

```
const socket = io();
```

At last, here is the server js:

```
var app = require('express')(); 
var server = require('http').Server(app); 
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I have looked at many other questions alike mine, but no answer has been able to change the outcome.
Most of the code is from the socket.io webpage, with some slight change. I have been trying to get this to word for so long, and I will happily answer any questions to try and get this work. Thanks! (I am not using localhost.)

The expected result is for the Engine.io request thing to have status code 200 instead of 404, and the server console to display that a user has connected.

Edit: I have now some further knowledge about my error, and I now know that adding " cors: origin="*" " doesn't work. Though I have seen one video about this that mentioned a supposed way to fix, this, my hosting service that I use doesn't seem to have that as an option for me. Still not solved!

Comment: "here is the server js" — What are you doing with the server.js?

Comment: `https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OUAHy-a` — Why are you making a request to the default `https` port when your Socket.io server is configured to run on port 3000 **without** any HTTPS? Is there a reverse proxy you didn't mention?

Comment: no, no proxy i am aware of

Comment: Then how is the request supposed to get to the server running on port 3000?

Comment: the thing is now, i don't really know what I am doing. I basically just hoped that would work..

Answer (score 1):

You have two HTTP servers.

1. Some unspecified server that is providing `https://example.com/` and is hosting your HTML and client-side JavaScript
2. The server that is created when you run `server.js` with Node.js (assuming you *are* running it at all).

The `io` function will, [by default](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#from-the-same-domain), try to connect to a socket.io instance **on the same origin**. Since your HTML document is running on *1* it tries to connect with socket.io to *1*.

Since your server which actually provides the socker.io service is *2* this results in a *404 Not Found* error.

As per [the documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#from-a-different-domain),  you need to specify the URL to server *2* so that you can connect to the socket.io service you've created.

```
 const socket = io("http://whereever.example.com:3000");
```

Note that you might hit problems trying to reach an unsecured (i.e. non-HTTPS) socket.io service from a secured origin.

Comment: Hiya! I now have this error:

"The page at 'https://foobar.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://foobar.example.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OUG5oM7'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Might this be due to the website redirecting me to https?

Comment: @Vairoon — It's because the socket.io server doesn't use HTTPS and the other one does, just like I pointed out in the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: Kinda don't understand stuff here, sorry, but do I specify for the client to send data to where I am running the server js file from? And, from what I understand, it does have to be http and not https. Currently, it is `const socket = io("http://foobar.example.com:3000");`, correct, no?

Comment: In general you should prefer HTTPS over HTTP. Mixing HTTP and HTTPS in a single page, as you are currently doing, doesn't work well. I don't know the URL to your server. The Node.js code you've written will run an HTTP server. You could make it an HTTPS server. You could put it behind an HTTPS reverse proxy. You could forget about Socket.io and use Websockets directly and have the server-side implementation be in a language supported by server #1.

Comment: can i simply change the ´const http = require('http');´ to ´const https = require('https');´ or is it more difficult than that?

Comment: You need to provide encryption certificates.

Comment: Well then. (Hosting service doesn't give me those files D: ) I have now removed https from my website in attempt of making this work. Now, since both the server and front page server should be the same, i hope.. It should work. But, it shows me errors. "http:// foobar.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OUGCePL 404 (Not Found)", should I still have the string inside the io() function?

Comment: Yes, but it needs to point to server #2 and, as I said, I don't know the URL to it.

Comment: Why should there be a server 2 now? I host the server from the same place you access the html and js. You access the stuff from http://foobar.example.com/ and I run the node.js server from the same folder, http://foobar.example.com/.

Comment: If you put two cars in the same garage then you still have two cars. They don’t magically merge into one car.

Comment: True, but now the thing is that the cars have the same plate, then how would I say "Oh, you need to go to foo-bar car!" when both are foo-bar?

Comment: They don't have the same plate. You can't run two different services (even if they use the same protocol) on the same network interface and port.

Comment: Huh, that's odd, since it really seems like I am. The html and the server.js is in the same directory. What would I do differently?

Comment: The directory you put server.js is more-or-less irrelevant (except that you probably don't want to publish its source code on a URL on your other web server so putting it in the same directory as the HTML file doesn't make sense). You execute server.js with Node.js which starts the web server that it is designed to run.

Comment: Well, why would the path and port and stuff be different from where the html is? What does noder.js change about where the server is ran?

Comment: Node.js doesn't change anything about where "the" server runs because there TWO DIFFERENT SERVERS. Node.js runs the second server. The source code of the second server is in *server.js*. Presumably that is why you named it *server.js*! The port will be different because (a) The JavaScript you wrote specified a different port and (b) You can't have two servers listening on the same port.

Comment: I also refer you to the the original text of the answer I wrote *which explains that already*.

Comment: The thing is, I still don't understand how to access the server that I ran with node.js on a SSH terminal (probably not best option, but I honestly don't know) and why would the address different? Why can't it access the correct place when everything just seems to be correct? It is all just problems... Everything is the same, but apparently not. Gahh